# webdriver get URL is not working although firefox instance gets opened but target URL is not processed

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver

package com.Angular;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Calculator {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
}
```

}

Comment: Please add firefox version and webdriver version. Could be that they are just incompatible.

Comment: My firefox version is "16.0.2"

Selenium JAR version is "selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0.jar"

Please note in my case Firefox Instance gets opened but URL is not gets inserted in to address bar.

Comment: Try firefox 48 or later. Not sure if selenium 3.0 supports versions like 16.0.2

Comment: I had the same issue 'url is not getting inserted' when I tried selenium 2.53 with firefox 49. When I've downgraded to FF 46 it worked.